# What DVI Ports Can I AndCan I Not Use With Other Cables

Tags: graphics-card, dvi

So I am getting a graphics card that has a Dual Link DVI-D output (x2). I only have a Dual Link DVI-D cable and a Single Link DVI-I cable at home however. My monitor allows a VGA and Dual Link DVI-I. My question is, can I use the SL-DVI-I cable to get graphics or does it have to be the exact. I looked at another question like this, but it was kind of hard to understand and a little bit convoluted. If you could just let me know if that will work it would bbe great, here is the link to my card if you need it: [MSI Radeon R9 390 Gaming 8GB](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127874&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-PCPartPicker,%20LLC-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3938566&SID=)

PS: If I can do this, would it affect quality at all or is it just a case of older plug and newer plug but they're cross compatible.

I heard this was possible buy just confirming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dual-link DVI is only necessary for very high resolution displays. If your display is 2560x1440 or higher, you'll need to use dual-link. Otherwise, a either dual-link or single-link cables will work.

Bear in mind current AMD cards (Radeon 2xx series and above) do not accept DVI-I connections. You must use a cable with a DVI-D connector on the graphics card end.

The real question is what monitor you have. If your monitor has a dual-link DVI-I input then it can accept *any* kind of DVI cable. DVI-I by its nature, accepts both DVI-A and DVI-D.

**Edit**

Some more clarification:

- A DVI-A output can only output an analogue (VGA) signal
- A DVI-I output can output both analogue (VGA) and digital (DVI-D) signals
- A DVI-D output can only output a digital signal
- A DVI-A input can only accept an analogue signal
- A DVI-I input should accept both analogue and digital signals
- A DVI-D input can only accept a digital signal

Your graphics card has DVI-D so it can only output digital.
**Your monitor has a DVI-I input so it will accept any kind of signal.**

- A DVI-I port will accept a DVI-D or DVI-I cable
- A DVI-D port will only accept a DVI-D cable
- DVI-A doesn't usually exist on it's own, as it's mainly for VGA compatibility

Your monitor has a DVI-D output so you can only connect a DVI-D cable to it.
**Your monitor has a DVI-I input so it will accept any kind of cable.**

Also please note the adapters suggested in the comments are passive adapters, only suitable for if you have the wrong kind of cable but your ports are inter-compatible. They will not work for connecting an analogue-only (DVI-A or VGA) monitor to a modern digital-only AMD card. You need an active signal converter for that such as [this one.](http://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-Active-Adapter-Converter-1920x1200/dp/B00C93JQXS)

Comment: This is a good answer.  I will just add that products like [DVI-D Male To DVI-I Female Adapter](http://www.amazon.com/Micro-Connectors-Female-Adapter-G08-223/dp/B000NWIQLU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1438956038&sr=8-1&keywords=DVI-D+to+DVI-I) and [DVI-D Female to DVI-I Male PC Connection Adapter](http://www.amazon.com/DVI-D-Female-Connection-Adapter-Converter/dp/B005EJQYZ2/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1438956038&sr=8-2&keywords=DVI-D+to+DVI-I) do exists

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, one is on the way but it won't be here for a few weeks, so I wanted something in the mean time!

Comment: @qasdfdsaq So I cannot use it then? It is an AMD card, so does that mean that I should go get a DVI-D cable instead?

Comment: You said you already had a DVI-D cable.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Oh, so that one will work?

Comment: @Ramhound My monitor takes the DVI-D though, I am already using it for my old PC. Do I still need the adapter?

Comment: @Nick - qasdfdsaq was pretty clear in his statements.  You can simply try it.  If the cable connects then you are good.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I'm new to DVI... Final question and then I'm done and I will accept the answer as soon as I can. Can I use my DVI-D Dual Link to connect to the card? (My monitor supports DVI-D Dual)... Sorry I'm such a pain!

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: @Nick - "So I am getting a graphics card that has a Dual Link DVI-D output" your next question "Can I use my DVI-D Dual Link to connect to the card?" is answered by the fact your card has DVI-D outputs.